# 10 element Array will only accept 5 integers during Selection sort project

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Ok, so this is for a Java class, but I'm not looking for someone to write the code, just help me debug this one. I want to enter 10 integers and have the inputs sorted in ascending order as they are entered then displayed, without any zeros (0) that may exist in the array.

Example of what the assignment should look like:

Enter 10 integers - one at a time...

Enter integer #1: 21

Sorted numbers: 21

Enter integer #2: 48

Sorted numbers: 21 48

Enter integer #3: 37

Sorted numbers: 21 37 48
etc....

I have tried a Selection Sort, Insertion and Bubble Sort, but the array will not hold or display more than 5 numbers.

Help.

Here is my Main:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    int j = 1;
    int[] list = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Enter 10 integers - one at a time...");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

        System.out.print("Enter integer #" + j + ": ");
        list[i] = input.nextInt();
        j++;

        //SortMethod.sort(list, list.length);
        SelectionSort.sort(list);
        //BubbleSort.sort(list);
        System.out.print("Sorted numbers: ");

        for(int p= 0; p<list.length; p++){  
            if (list[p] !=0)

                System.out.print(list[p] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }   
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
}
```

Here is my Selection Sort:

```
public class SelectionSort {


public static void sort (int[] list){
    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
     {
        for(int j=i+1; j<list.length; j++)
        {
            if(list[i] > list[j] )
            {
                int temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[i];
                list[i] = temp;
            }
        }
     }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting that it will only take 5 integers? Is an exception being thrown, input not accepted, etc

Comment: First of all, you're declaring Scanner input twice. That should give you an error.

Comment: Why? It is just unneeded redeclaration, but errors? rly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `List` insteed of array and ready-to-go sorting implementations from jdk -> `Collections.sort()` ?

Anyway the problem is that you are inserting new integers into already sorted array and that causes disfunction of your code. So as you inserting new elements on indexes 0,1,2,3,4 - sorting algorithm moves them to positions 5,6,7,8,9. From this point your inputs starts overriding sorted values with new ones from input - (Main loop i>=5).All in all, it accepted 10 integers, but 5 of them where kindly overriten.

Here is little modified version of your work whitch works like you want. Analyze it!

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int j = 1;
        int[] list = new int[11];

        System.out.println("Enter 10 integers - one at a time...");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {

            System.out.print("Enter integer #" + j + ": ");
            list[0] = input.nextInt();
            j++;

            //SortMethod.sort(list, list.length);
            SelectionSort.sort(list);
            //BubbleSort.sort(list);
            System.out.print("Sorted numbers: ");

            for (int p = 1; p < list.length; p++) {
                if (list[p] != 0)

                    System.out.print(list[p] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}

class SelectionSort {

    public static void sort(int[] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
                if (list[i] > list[j]) {
                    int temp = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[i];
                    list[i] = temp;
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was perfect! There are two things I don't understand.
1. Why set the list array to 11 for a 10 integer array?
2. Why do I set input.nextInt() to array position 0 each time?
#2, is that because the selection method sets them to 1, 2, etc?
Thanks again for your help debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing sorted value with  `list[i] = input.nextInt();` with every input. So, `5` values always `0` in `list`. Use `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]` and add new value to `List<Integer>`. Try following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int j = 1;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("Enter 10 integers - one at a time...");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        System.out.print("Enter integer #" + j + ": ");
        list.add(input.nextInt());
        j++;

        //SortMethod.sort(list, list.length);
//        SelectionSort.sort(list);
        Collections.sort(list);
        //BubbleSort.sort(list);
        System.out.print("Sorted numbers: ");

        for(int p= 0; p<list.size(); p++){  
            if (list.get(p) !=0)
                System.out.print(list.get(p) + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }   
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to learn the List method... I think that is a more effective process, however, this class project was based on standard Arrays. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I just modified the lines below the comments I put (temp declaration and for loop).
This changes makes program support negative numbers too, read the comments below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int j = 1;
    int[] list = new int[11];

    System.out.println("Enter 10 integers - one at a time...");

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter integer #" + j + ": ");

    // Add temporal variable to store input
        int temp = input.nextInt();
    // Check for empty place in list (as far as it seems you don't care about zeros)
        for (int p = 0; p < list.length; p++) {
                if (list[p] == 0) {
                    list[p] = temp;
                    break;
                }
        }

        j++;

        //SortMethod.sort(list, list.length);
        SelectionSort.sort(list);
        //BubbleSort.sort(list);
        System.out.print("Sorted numbers: ");

        for (int p = 1; p < list.length; p++) {
            if (list[p] != 0)

                System.out.print(list[p] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
}
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I think I understand your edits too. Thanks for adding the comments.